# can i submit my OS4 APP using release mode of iphone 3G?

Tags: iphone

my OS4 app is running good in debug mode on my 3G but can i submit this app to appstore or i need to build release mode on Iphone4???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to test on an iPhone 4, but you do need to test on iOS 4.0, which you should be able to do on your iPhone 3G.

You should most definitely test a build in the Release configuration, which is what you'll be submitting anyways.

Comment: thanks a lot now i am clear and confident will up my app tonight :-)